# La función write() no me acepta string ni bytes (bytes-like object is required, not 'str')

Tags: python, python-3.x, archivo, codificación

Estoy intentando escribir unos datos en un fichero y me estoy volviendo loco. :-)

Los datos vienen de una lista que fue seteada así

```
def func(res):
   playlists = []  
   for item in res["items"]:
    lists.append("%s # %s" % (item["id"], item["snippet"]["title"]))
  return lists
```

Si lo pongo así, falla cuando se encuentra un cáracter en una codicicación deiferente.

```
 with open(args.filename, "w") as f:
  for i in lists:
   f.write("%s\n" % i )      
 f.close()
```

Si lo pongo de una de estas dos formas en el fichero se escribe con una molesta b al príncipio (b'una frase') y no se quita ni ajustando las opciones del NotePad++.

```
   f.write("%s\n" % i.encode("utf-8") )      

   f.write("%s\n" % i.encode("cp1252", errors="ignore") )
```

***A partir de aquí intente escribir el archivo en modo binario con la opción "wb":***

```
with open(args.filename, "wb") as f:
```

Si lo hago así me da este error (a bytes-like object is required, not 'str')

```
   f.write("%s\n" i.encode("utf-8")  )
```

Si lo pongo así también me da el mismo error

```
   i = bytes(i, 'utf-8')
   f.write("%s\n" i )
```

Sé que el problema es porque estoy intentado escribir el fichero en modo binario. Pero ni ídea de como se soluciona.

¿Alguna otra posibilidad para escribir en el fichero?

Comment: Si abres el archivo en modo "w" estas escribiendo en un archivo de texto no en un archivo binario. Usa el argumento `encoding` de `open` en función de la codificación de tus cadenas en la lista: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#open. Por cierto, la línea `f.close()` es innecesaria, de eso se encarga `with`

Comment: Si, el tema es que no se la codificación de las cadenas, creo que falla porque son caracteres multibyte. Es decir creo que son emoticonos o simbolos de ese estilo. Tambien puede que haya alguna que otra cosa en ruso!! :-) Ok, creo que borré demasiado para resumir... en los tres últimos casos estaba usando la opción "wb" para escribir el archivo (lo voy a escribir ahi arriba)

Comment: ¿Alguna forma de convertir el string a un bytes-like object  y que se pueda escribir el fichero en modo binario? (Si esa es la solución para que no salga esa dichosa b' al principio de la cadena)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

al final tuve que eliminar la lista y el append, al parecer eran esas cosas las que estaban dando problemas. No entiendo por qué pero sin ellas se puede escribir en el archivo y todo funciona perfecto.

El código al final quedó así:

```
def func(res, filename):
 f= open(filename, "wb")  
   for item in res["items"]:    
    str = item["id"] + " # " + item["snippet"]["title"] + "\n"
    f.write(str.encode("utf-8"))
 f.close()
```

Y estos son los simbolos que estaban amargandome la vida...
⚡️   ♛    <-- Malditos!!! :-)

Si alguien sabe porque la lista estaba dando esos problemas con la escritura binaria y me quiere sacar de la ignorancia yo le estaría muy agradecido!!